# jquery timepicker plugin like selection/selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jquery timepicker plugin like :

[image: timepicker]

Can any body please tell me, where can i find this kind of plugin, when i searched, i got slider kind of plugins, but this is the required.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: ive also searched for a time picker. let me tell you, they all suck. nothing can beat the UX of typing in a time, or using 2 select boxes. any other solution is going to take up a lot of screen realestate or give you 5 minute increments.

Answer (score 3):

I built this timepicker plugin to match the jQuery datepicker style, maybe you will like it : http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker

[image: Timepicker]